# reverse jQuery.().prevUntil()

Tags: javascript, jquery

> The new jQuery object that is returned
>   contains all previous siblings up to
>   but not including the one matched by
>   the `.prevUntil()` selector; the
>   elements are returned in order from
>   the `closest` sibling to the `farthest`.

how to reverse the order from the `farthest` to `closest`, or maybe, is there any js function to reverse the object returned by `.prevUntil()` ?

Answer (score 3):

I would say something like:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call($('.selector').prevUntil('.new_selector')).reverse()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem and finally found a solution. Had to ditch the prevUntil and prevAll selectors because of the reverse order. Here is what I finally settled on for my solution:

```
$(".js-readmore").each(function(){
  var prevElems = $(this).siblings().not($(this).next());
  $(prevElems).wrapAll('<div class="readmore-collapse"></div>');
});
```

Basically just using the siblings selector and adding a filter to not include next items.